# SocketException while startHandshake on SSLSocket

Tags: java, apache, security, ssl

When I try connect to apache server on port 443 via SSLSocket i get:

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed):
...
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1429)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
```

When I'm using command to verify connect with openssl i get correct response:

openssl s_client -host 127.0.0.1 -port 443 -CAfile ./cacert.pem

..
Verify return code: 0 (ok)

I tried to load certificate from pem file to keystore.

```
        String CA_FILE = "/tmp/cacert.pem";

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(CA_FILE);
        X509Certificate ca = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new BufferedInputStream(fis));

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null, null);
        ks.setCertificateEntry(Integer.toString(1), ca);

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(ks);

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sc.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        SSLSocketFactory ssf = sc.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket("127.0.0.1", 443);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( socket.getOutputStream())));
        socket.startHandshake();
```

NOTE: added log from -Djavax.net.debug=all:

```
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 58, 21, 233, 153, 59, 238, 221, 130, 144, 188, 165, 169 }
***
update handshake state: finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 24
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 3A 15 E9 99   3B EE DD 82 90 BC A5 A9  ....:...;.......
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 10
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 2
0000: 02 0A                                              ..
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
main, called closeSocket()
```

Comment: Run your jvm with ```-Djavax.net.debug=all``` and update your post with the details.

Comment: What do Apache logs say? (you can increase their verbosity if needed)